# Creating sections with big background images and bad performance in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scroll, parallax

I have a one-page website and I've added some sections with big background images set on them. I wanted them to have a "fixed" effect so when user scrolls they don't move. So I used `background-size: cover;` and `background-attachment: fixed`. This does the job. The problem however, is it's extremely laggy in Chrome, I think chrome doesn't cache images or something. You can test it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sallar/rwyfZ/1/

its not smooth like other browsers. So I tried using images (in this case using $.backstretch). Using this method the scrolling lag is fixed and scrolls very smoothly, but it doesn't have the "fixed" effect I wanted. So I thought I should use a parallax effect. But none of the parallax plugins or methods I tried did a good a job on "images", they were all optimized for background-image which I can't use because of that problem in Chrome.

Here is a demo of Backstretch example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sallar/FX4Cn/1/

So, What should I do to make them have a fixed style and make the page scroll smoothly like the second example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the file(s) type/size?

Comment: @bobthyasian JPG, 800 ~ 1000 or 1100 in width. You can see them in the URLs above

Comment: FYI--I don't notice any great lag time difference in Chrome on my Win7 machine.

Comment: This isn't an answer but it might help. Convert to PNG, smaller files with little to no loss in quality. When it comes to Chrome, it's very powerful but it has it's faults, such as being a resource hog.

Comment: I'm not a Web Designer but what do you mean by scroll-lag because I didn't see any lag when scrolling your first fiddler!

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any big difference except that the second one isnt fixed for sure.

I think your "issue" is that Chrome scrolls in steps, what Firefox and Opera dont (i dont really know about the others atm). Next time you may try to google something like "smooth scrolling chrome" to see one of hundrets questions and solutions for this "problem".

It theoretically is possible to do this with Javascript, but i cant find any useful/working example atm.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a big difference when it's run in full-with. I tried searching a dozen times. Everybody has this problem and no one can solve it.

Comment: Then still, i cant see any lag

Comment: Sallar Kaboli, I am having this problem as well. Did you ever find an answer?